# Sign Up OTP issue in android app

Tags: android, firebase

In my android app, there's an issue that I am not receiving otp for sign up so I cannot signup on a device after generating signed apk. But when it test it in a test device using an USB cable connected to the studio it's working great. Please help me with the issue

Thanks

Comment: If you talking about one time password you have to debug your sms gateway integration code if it sending sms and its delivered or not

Comment: I get one time password when i run using usb cable but as soon as i generate a signed apk and test on the same device after uninstalling the exisiting app its not working and there's no error also

Comment: Can you help using team-viewer to solve it as i am feed up and getting no solutions

Comment: Canot help over teamviewer but you can toast the success and filure messages on signed apk

Comment: Any way else you can help out as there's no error in coding and testing